# How to Parse String to Image with JSON on Android?

Tags: android, json

Again hi. I return android parsing with JSON. Now, i can successfully parsing but i dont get a picture. We stored picture as String on database. So, i think must convert String to Image for display in `ImageView`. I try this function but i can't use:

```
public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString) {

byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
 return bitmap; }
```

And this **my activiy class**:

```
 newsList = new ArrayList<>();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    JSONArray news= jsonObj.getJSONArray("news");

                        JSONObject r = news.getJSONObject(0);
                        String Id = r.getString("Id");
                        String NewsDetail = r.getString("NewsDetail");
                        String Picture= r.getString("Picture");

                        HashMap<String, String> News = new HashMap<>();

                        News.put("Id", Id);
                        News.put("NewsDetail", NewsDetail);
                        News.put("Picture", Picture);

                    newsList.add(News);
                }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    NewsDip.this, newsList,
                    R.layout.news_list, new String[]{"Picture"},
                    new int[]{R.id.imageView});
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

I think I use this function in adapter. But I can't do it. How can I solve this?

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: why can't you use it in adapter???

Comment: @KaranMer i can parsing by String. But when i use this " Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString)" function, i can't use in my adapter. I try "Bitmap bm = StringToBitMap(Picture); MyPhoto.setImageBitmap(bm); " but adapter don't accept

Comment: Use custom adapter and load image with _Glide_

Comment: Then make a custom one. check this https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2016/09/android-recyclerview-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library to simply show your byte converted image

add this in Gradle

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```

add this in your java file

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(encodeByte)   //your byte array
    .asBitmap()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_broken)
    .into(your imageview);
```

Comment: I add Gradle. But where is add in java? In adapter?

Comment: after this line  byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);